# Bulk user account creation from CSV data import/ingestion

Tags: sql, web-applications, azure, ssis, bulkinsert

Hi all brilliant minds,

I am currently working on a fairly complex problem and I would love to get some idea brainstorming going on. I have a C# .NET web application running in Windows Azure, using SQL Azure as the primary datastore.

Everytime a new user creates an account, all they need to provide is the name, email and password. Upon account creation, we store the core membership data to the SQL database, and all the secondary operations (e.g. sending emails, establishing social relationships, creating profile assets, etc) get pushed onto an Azure Queue and gets picked-up/processed later.

Now I have a couple of CSV files that contain hundreds of new users (names & emails) that need to be created on the system. I am thinking of automating this by breaking into two parts:

**Part 1: Write a service that ingests the CSV files, parses out the names & emails, and saves this data in storage A**

- This service should be flexible enough to take files with different formats
- This service does not actually create the user accounts, so this is decoupled from the business logic layer of our application
- The choice of storage does not have to be SQL, it could also be non-relational datastore
  (e.g. Azure Tables)
- This service could be a third-party solution outside of our application platform - so it is open to all suggestions

**Part 2: Write a process that periodically goes through storage A and creates the user accounts from there**

- This is in the "business logic layer" of our application
- Whenever an account is successfully created, mark that specific record in storage A as processed
- This needs to be retry-able in case of failures in user account creations

I'm wondering if anyone has experience with importing bulk "users" from files, and if what I am suggesting sounds like a decent solution.

Note that Part 1 could be a third-party solution outside of our application platform, so there's no restriction in what language/platform it has to be running in. We are thinking about either using [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), or [Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 2008 (SSIS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) that ingests and loads data from CSV into SQL datastore. If anyone has worked with these and can provide some pointers that would be greatly appreciated too.. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: +1 for calling me brilliant

Comment: You are very welcome. Most stackoverflow users are!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly, you already have a process that picks up messages from a queue and does its core logic to create the user assets/etc.  So, sounds like you should only automate the parsing of the CSV files and dumping the contents into queue messages?  That sounds like a trivial task.

You can kick the process of processing the CSV file also via a queue message (to a different queue).  The message would contain the location of the CSV file and the Worker Role running in Azure would pick it up (could be the same worker role as the one that processes new users if the usual load is not high).

Since you're utilizing queues, the process is retriable

HTH

Comment: Thanks Igorek, queues sound like a good option especially because it has retrying and throttling mechanisms, and we have more control over the import. I'll give it some thought. Thanks!